# QGIS Offset Points by value

Tags: qgis, point, layers, line, offset

I've got one layer with a line (e. g. a road) and one layer with points (e. g. trees along the road). So far, the points are placed right on the line, but the attribute table of the point layer has a column called "distance", that lists the distance of the trees to the middle of the road. So is there a possibility to automatically offset the points from the line by the individual distance value?

Comment: This should be perfectly doable using `translate geometry` with data defined override incorporating Pythagoras after adding the line angle to the points.

Comment: Is there a relation between roads and trees? I.e. does the tree layer have the road id as attribute?

Comment: @geozelot: Yes, the road ID is another attribute of the tree layer.

Comment: ...and is there a relative side attribute or rule? E.g. 'to the right, in direction of the linestring'?

Comment: Yes, if the number is positive, the tree stands at the right side, left is negative

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `Expression String Builder` on the `Offset X, Y` of the `Label Placement` using something like `Array("distance",0)`. If the distance is in meters use `Meters at Scale` for example.

[image]

**EDIT:** Miss-read your question and I thought you want to place the label. So if you want to place the symbol based on the distance offset you can do something similar and use the `Offset` property of the `Single Symbol`.

[image]

Comment: Wow, thats much easier than I expected! It works perfectly, thank you very much! :-)